# Merge two csv files as seperate work sheets

Tags: shell, csv, merge

I have two csv files and would like to merge them a separate sheets in CSV. is it possible?

I have tried

```
cat first.csv second.csv > final.csv

join -t, first.csv second.csv > final.csv
```

Comment: if you're planning to use the `.csv` files inside of an Excel spreadsheet, then you you will need to auotmate the process inside of Excel or find a MS Windows based utility that can do this. The `perl` language has modules available that might support this, but it will have a high learning curve. Maybe same for `python`. Good luck.

Comment: sheets option is not available for csv format. Sheets option is provided only on MS excel format.